# Green Card Application in Northern Cyprus

Tags: usa, visa, greencard, turkey

I am citizen of Turkey and working in Northern Cyprus. I want to apply for Green Card. How should i mention my country of residence? Should it be Turkey or Cyprus?

Answer (score 1):

Since the US [does not recognize an independent country in northern Cyprus](https://www.state.gov/r/pa/ei/bgn/5376.htm), where you reside, you should select *Cyprus.*  You certainly do not reside in Turkey, since no state considers northern Cyprus to be part of Turkey.

You suggest in a comment that international mail must be addressed to Turkey, which makes sense if no other country recognizes Northern Cyprus.  I would therefore choose *Turkey* for the country (item (g)) in the mailing address (item 8), and *Cyprus* for the "country where you live today" (item 9).

Comment: @TomasBy as I understand it, Turkey recognizes Northern Cyprus as an independent state, which in turn means that Turkey does not consider Northern Cyprus to be part of Turkey.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But the problem is when you expect to receive something from abroad you need to write "Northern Cyprus, Mersin 10, Turkey" as address. Otherwise it ends up in Republic of Cyprus which makes it almost impossible for me to get what i want.

Comment: @yozby is the question about number 8(g) (mailing address/country) or number 9 (country where you live today)?

Comment: about where i live